# Applying energy conservation to two sphere system with leaking charge

Tags: energy-conservation

> Two identical charged spheres suspended from a common point by two massless strings of length l, are initially at a distance (x<<l) apart because of their mutual repulsion. The charge begins to leak from both the spheres at a constant rate. As a result the spheres approach each other with velocity v. Then v varies as a function of distance x between the spheres as

Find proportionality relation between v and x

The correct answer is 'd' but i'm having trouble reaching it,

MY work:

Consider $ma=k\frac{q^2}{x^2}$

$ m v dv = k \frac{q^2}{x^2} dx$

$ \frac{mv^2}{2} = k \frac{q^2}{x}$

This gives me option(b)

But, supposedly, the answer is 'd'

My friend told you could solve it using energy conservation but I can't understand how energy is conserved when the charge is changing. Like, doesn't change charge change energy.

Comment: As $q$ is also varying, you have to also find a relation between $q$ and $x$. Please don't post image of the question rather type it.

Comment: I think there is something wrong this same question ,I have encountered 2 times and always the answer was $v$ proportional to $x^{-1/2}$ as in this case.

Comment: https://edurev.in/question/1439036/Two-identical-charged-spheres-suspended-from-a-com see this , I think either your answer key was wrong or you have misread it, however your technique by which you are getting that answer is not right